# PHP - Variable value not printing as html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print php variable which contains html tag in it. I want to display it as html but it is print it as plain text.
Below is my code:

```
$final= $first . $second . $third;
echo $final;
echo htmlentities($final);
echo htmlspecialchars($final);
```

**$first** value is `<iframe`

**$second** value is `width="960" height="540"`

**$third** value is `src="" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>`

so **$final** combine string of all 3 variable which I intend to display it as an iframe. But it just display text as below:

```
<iframe width="960" height="540" src="" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you use `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's happening because you are using the incorrect method `htmlentities` OR `htmlspecialchars`. Remember that those methods converts HTML into **characters**. If you want to print the HTML from String, you need to use `html_entity_decode`.

```
echo html_entity_decode($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
$first = '<iframe';
$second = ' width="960" height="540" ';
$third = 'src="" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';

$final= $first . $second . $third;
echo $final;
```

OR

Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters write down below code http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

```
echo html_entity_decode($final);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think that adding spaces here and there solve the problem of escaped HTML tags?

Comment: @NicoHaase no need for downvote for that. He also removed the htmlentities and htmlspecialchars. And the formatting of the backicks in question doesn't show a space after `<iframe` which he's right about, He thinked that it'll show up as `<iframewidth`.

Comment: @NicoHaase because without adding space check in browser html tag might be look like this

<iframewidth="960" height="540" src="" allowfullscreen="true"></iframewidth="960">

Comment: @TahaPaksu that's why I've asked for an explanation of that code. The code in the question shows that the case of strings connected without using spaces between them (where the result would contain `iframewidth`) does not occur

Comment: I still wouldn't downvote a new contributor's answer even if he writes junk without getting an explanation of himself. Instead I would try to teach him how to correct his mistakes.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I can't see space in his Question that why I write this code.

Comment: @TahaPaksu you're right, downvoting was not the proper reaction. But currently, SO won't let me take it back until the answer is edited

Comment: @NicoHaase I cant understand why give down votes It's working fine in browser. I also tested code

Comment: The most important point in writing answers on SO is not solving the problem, but explaining what was wrong before and how you solved it. Someone reading your answer should be able to learn from it, and that is not possible if the main parts of the answer are not explained

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer! Still, you suggest to add some spaces - can you explain why that should be neccessary? Please add such explanation to the answer, not to the comment section, to make it more visible to someone reading your answer